# N+1 Issue with polymorphic association and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run into an N+1 issue when attempting to perform a calculation on a polymorphic association.

**My Model:**

```
class FoodOrder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
    has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy, as: :order
    has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: "Product"

    def productsOfType(type_of_product)
        orderables.where(category: type_of_product).sum(:quantity)
    end

    def total_items
        return productsOfType('general') + productsOfType('is_limited') + productsOfType('nuzest')
    end
end
```

I attempt to eagerly load the association:

```
client = Client.includes(food_orders: [:order_items, :orderables]).find(params[:client_id])
```

But when I call `:total_items` I get the N+1.

```
client.food_orders.map {|food_order| food_order.total_items}

# response

   (24.5ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 17441], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 0]]
   (24.2ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 17441], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 1]]
   (24.1ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 17441], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 3]]
   (23.9ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 18917], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 0]]
   (23.9ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 18917], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 1]]
   (23.6ms)  SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "products"."id" = "order_items"."orderable_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1 AND "order_items"."order_type" = $2 AND "order_items"."orderable_type" = $3 AND "products"."category" = $4  [["order_id", 18917], ["order_type", "FoodOrder"], ["orderable_type", "Product"], ["category", 3]]
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to count the leaves on a tree by starting with the trunk and following it through the branches.  Your code is saying to climb the tree and then go to each branch.  In rails you want to count leaves by counting the leaves and qualifying those leaves by the trunk.

I'm not sure if I have your model right...

```
types_of_interest = ['general', 'is_limited', 'nuzest']
Product.joins(order_items: :food_order).merge(FoodOrder.where(id: food_order.id)).where(category: types_of_interest).sum(:quantity)
```

Grab the products of those types that are part of that order and sum the quantities.

Comment: I think the issue is that I need to end up with an array of food orders and this will result in Products.  I'm trying to perform a query to load all the client's food orders and their products up front and then loop through them, calculating total items w/o hitting the DB again.  I think this is on the right track but not quite there

Comment: I got to this point but the summation still hits the DB each time.  Ideally there'd be 1 query even though I'm looping through each food order. `food_orders = FoodOrder.includes(:order_items).joins(:client, {order_items: :product})
.merge(Product.where(category: ['general', 'is_limited', 'nuzest'])).where(clients: {id: client.id})`.  I can then call `food_orders.map {|fo| fo.order_items}` w/o hitting the DB, but `food_orders.map {|fo| fo.order_items.sum(:quantity)}` still does :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
client.food_orders.select('food_orders.id, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity').group('food_orders.id')
```

You will have to add other fields to your select clause for any other fields you need to access but it is an OK starting point.  You also might need to use left_joins() if you need to return clients without orders.

Answer (score 0):

First, `Eager Loading` doesn't work the way as you expected.

Let's take an example:

```rb
# Eager loading orderables by includes
orders = client.food_orders.includes(:orderables)

# Way 1, will trigger extra queries as `sum(:filed_name)` method (From Rails) will generate SQL query
orders.map { |order| order.orderables.sum(:quantity) }

# Way 2, won't trigger extra queries as orderables already loaded
orders.map { |order| order.orderables.sum { |orderable| orderable.quantity } }
```

Then to your code.

1. The code could be simplified to:

```rb
class FoodOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy, as: :order
  has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: "Product"

  # Will reduce queries to one third, but can't resolve N+1 as the above example stated
  def total_items
    orderables.where(category: ['general', 'is_limited', 'nuzest'])).sum(:quantity)
  end
end
```

2. The `sum` method actually closer to `Product` model, so we could move it to there:

```rb
class FoodOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy, as: :order
  has_many :orderables, through: :order_items, source: :orderable, source_type: "Product"

  def total_items
    orderables.total_quantities
  end
end

class Product
  belongs_to :food_order

  scope :total_quantities, -> { where(category: ['general', 'is_limited', 'nuzest'])).sum(:quantity) }
end
```

3. We want to do some calculation to the `Product` model, so instead of using `client.food_orders.map { ... }`, we could resolve `N+1` and simplify the code to:

```rb
Product.joins(food_order: :client)
       .where(clients: { id: params[:client_id] })
       .total_quantities
```

Answer (score 0):

First about `FoodOrder` model

`productsOfType` method name is not associated with its body and doesn't match Ruby convention. It should be like this

```rb
def products_by_type(product_type)
  orderables.where(category: product_type)
end
```

If you need to sum all the categories, you don't need to call them explicitly. Why don't call them just this way:

```rb
food_order.orderables.sum(:quantity)
```

Or if you need explicitly some categories, like this:

```rb
food_order.products_by_type(%w[general is_limited nuzest]).sum(:quantity)
```

In this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475041/n1-issue-with-polymorphic-association-and-sum#comment134854388_76476383) you write:

> `food_orders = FoodOrder.includes(:order_items).joins(:client, {order_items: :product}).merge(Product.where(category: ['general', 'is_limited', 'nuzest'])).where(clients: {id: client.id})`. I can then call `food_orders.map {|fo| fo.order_items}` w/o hitting the DB, but `food_orders.map {|fo| fo.order_items.sum(:quantity)}` still does :(

You can fix like this

```rb
food_orders.sum { |fo| fo.order_items.quantity }
```

It is `sum` with block instead of `sum` with symbol

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, most ORM have this issue. How an ORM parses the code written is somewhat like this:

for every row received in the first query, run a query that gets the sum of that `id` in the row.

Instead, you should tell the ORM to get the sum of every `id` or whatever you want to sum by (might be name or product SKU, it depends on the context). In more technical terms, sum and group by the keys you want the sum to give you a proper result.

If your model has relations, inner join the relations in the query and have the sum as a field in the query and group by the keys necessary.

This will result in one query that gets the data from the database and runs the aggregate function `SUM` on the data set with the `group by` constraint.

Ben Trewern provides a simple example for the explanation I've written in his answer.

Hope this general information will solve your `n + 1` issue.